# fatal: No existing author found with 'XXX'

Tags: git-commit, git-config, git

I used git for the first time and I set my user name and user mail. The commands I used are below:

```
git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"
git config user.email "bob@example.com"
git config --global user.name "bob"
git config user.name "bob"
```

When I run `git commit --author "bob"` , I got an error `fatal: No existing author found with 'bob'`. How can I set user name and email?

Comment: You wouldn't normally want to set your user/email anywhere but in the global config, so the commands where you don't have "--global" probably aren't what you want.  Once you have done that just use `git commit` without "--author"

Comment: I tried without "--author" and it was ok. thanks for your help

Comment: This is an example of why git is not user-friendly.

Comment: the format should be 'Bob <bob@email.com>'

Comment: It can also happen when you don't have permission to push to the repository. Make sure to check if you are added as a committer to the repo.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should stop using `--author` each time you commit, and instead configure an author with `git config`. Once you've done so, you can type `git commit` and the author will be pulled from your `.gitconfig` file.

If you want to give `--author` a name to use for authoring the commit, you need to use

`bob <bob@example.com>`

not just `bob`. If your author string doesn't match the `user <user@example.com>` format, Git assumes you've given it a search pattern, and it will try to find commits with matching authors. It will use the first found commit's `user <user@example.com>` as the author.

Comment: In Android Studio for private project with permission to User, you need to add `User <user@example.com>` to the author section when commit.

Answer (score 22):

This command will do the trick:

```
git commit --amend -C HEAD --reset-author
```

Comment: All this did was make it unable to detect the changes I wanted to commit.

Comment: I just wanted to change the most recent commit, so I omitted the `-C HEAD`.

Answer (score 7):

Note: starting with Git 2.3.1+ (Q1/Q2 2015), the error message will be more explicit.
See [commit 1044b1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1044b1f6a1a56ae723fd19cddd769380dc775f48) by [Michael J Gruber (`mjg`)](https://github.com/mjg):

> #### `commit`: reword `--author` error message

> If an `--author` argument is specified but does not contain a '`>`' then git tries to find the argument within the existing authors; and gives the error message "`No existing author found with '%s'`" if there is no match.
>
> This is confusing for users who try to specify a valid complete author
> name.
>
> Rename the error message to make it clearer that the failure has two
> reasons in this case.

The solution remains to have the config user.name and user.email properly set, but for the case where `--author` is used, at least the expected argument is now clearer.

So run:

```
git add --all ; git commit -m "$git_msg" \
    --author "First Last <first.last@company.com>"; git push
```

Answer (score 1):

For my experience, don't forget `<>`
The correct format is

```
git commit --amend --author="bob <bob@example.com>"`
```

But

```
git commit --amend --author="bob bob@example.com"
```

will show `is not 'Name <email>' and matches no existing author`