# Python sh, set user.email to commit (Git)

Tags: python, django, git, sh

I'm working with [Waliki](https://github.com/mgaitan/waliki/), specifically with waliki.git,

Waliki.git use sh to manage Git, so there, when execute a commit, user ever is setted to  `settings.WALIKI_COMMITTER_EMAIL`,
looking for source (as next), `user` at `.git/config` never is changed.

```
class Git(object):
    __shared_state = {}     # it's a Borg

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        from waliki.settings import WALIKI_DATA_DIR
        self.content_dir = WALIKI_DATA_DIR
        os.chdir(self.content_dir)
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.content_dir, '.git')):
            git.init()
            git.config("user.email", settings.WALIKI_COMMITTER_EMAIL)
            git.config("user.name", settings.WALIKI_COMMITTER_NAME)    
        self.git = git

    def commit(self, page, message='', author=None, parent=None, extra_path=None):
        path = page.path
        paths_to_commit = [path]
        if extra_path:
            paths_to_commit.append(extra_path)
        kwargs = {}
        if isinstance(author, User) and author.is_authenticated():
            kwargs['author'] = u"%s <%s>" % (author.get_full_name() or author.username, author.email)
        elif isinstance(author, six.string_types):
            kwargs['author'] = author

        try:
            there_were_changes = parent and parent != self.last_version(page)
            status = git.status('--porcelain', path).stdout.decode('utf8')[:2]
            if parent and status != "UU":
                git.stash()
                git.checkout('--detach', parent)
                try:
                    git.stash('pop')
                except:
                    git.checkout('--theirs', path)

            if status == 'UU':
                # See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8062976/811740
                kwargs['i'] = True

            git.add(path)
            git_commit_cmd = git.commit.bake(allow_empty=True, allow_empty_message=True, m=message, **kwargs)
            git_commit_cmd('--', *paths_to_commit)
            last = self.last_version(page)
            if parent and status != "UU":
                git.checkout('master')
                git.merge(last)
        except ErrorReturnCode as e:
            # TODO: make this more robust!
            error = e.stdout.decode('utf8')
            if 'CONFLICT' in error:
                # For '-i' attribute see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5827944/811740
                git_commit_cmd = git.commit.bake(allow_empty=True, allow_empty_message=True, m=_('Merged with conflict'), i=True, **kwargs)
                git_commit_cmd('--', *paths_to_commit)
                raise Page.EditionConflict(_('Automatic merge failed. Please, fix the conflict and save the page.'))
            else:
                raise
        return there_were_changes
```

I add some code, so:

class Git(object):
        __shared_state = {}     # it's a Borg

```
    def __init__(self, author):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        from waliki.settings import WALIKI_DATA_DIR
        self.content_dir = WALIKI_DATA_DIR
        os.chdir(self.content_dir)
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.content_dir, '.git')):
            git.init()
            git.config("user.email", settings.WALIKI_COMMITTER_EMAIL)
            git.config("user.name", settings.WALIKI_COMMITTER_NAME)    
        else:
            git.config("user.email", author)
            git.config("user.name", author)
        self.git = git
```

but Got:

```
  RAN: '/usr/bin/git --no-pager commit -m Page created --allow-empty --allow-empty-message --author=rizotastack@gmail.com -- content.md'

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
fatal: No existing author found with 'rizotastack@gmail.com'
```

How I can do Git set rightly current user to commit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal: No existing author found with 'XXX'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318375/fatal-no-existing-author-found-with-xxx)

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of interest:

```
    if isinstance(author, User) and author.is_authenticated():
        kwargs['author'] = u"%s <%s>" % (author.get_full_name() or author.username, author.email)
    elif isinstance(author, six.string_types):
        kwargs['author'] = author
```

You need to specify the author with the format `Full Name <email@example.com>`.

[From the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

```
--author=<author>

Override the commit author. Specify an explicit author using the standard
"A U Thor <author@example.com>" format. Otherwise <author> is assumed to be a
pattern and is used to search for an existing commit by that author (i.e.
rev-list --all -i --author=<author>); the commit author is then copied from the
first such commit found.
```

Comment: Right, this is the problem, so, I use a custom user, there `kwargs['author'] = author` , now I do `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`
`User = get_user_model()` but get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: since this is a different error, I would suggest opening another question with more details. questions that are too specific or that have too many parts are not useful to other users; there is less chance that one person can fully answer the multipart question as a whole.