# How to set default git author in Intellij permanently

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I want to set the default `author` on the `Version Control` window in Intellij. I always need to type again and again when I'm commiting new code.

Is there any way to set that value by default without needing to edit in every commit I make?

[image: Intellij Version Control Window]

I've already set git `user` and `email` on my `~/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
email = my-email@domain.com
name = waghcwb
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have set your `user.name` and `user.email` in your `~/.gitconfig` you can just leave the Author field empty and Git will look in `~/.gitconfig` .

Comment: Sorry but by 2018.2 community this is not working. Neither the local config nor the global one. And, bad decision of the author of this feature. What if every repo has its own config? Shouldn't it search locally first in current repo and then in global setting?

Comment: This is a pity indeed but how is downvoting an answer which obviously predates the version fair?

Comment: If it is not the answer, I downvote. I mean, if I don't set locally the username and email, this should applies. If I set it locally, this should not. And, in my case, this is not the answer because I have done it as you said and nothing happens. And the upvote to my comment has suggested the same. I am sorry.

Comment: Note that setting in ~/.gitconfig is global for all your git projects whereas setting in .git/config is on a per-project basis

Answer (score 4):

Go to your project where git is **initialized**.

Then enable the hidden folders and find "`.git`" and go inside the folder.

Find the file called "`config`" and add below code and save.

```
[user]
      name = username
      email = username@domaim.com
```

This will set default git author in Intellij permanently

Comment: I also hope this is the case but no, it does not affect. 2018.2 community.

Comment: This initially seemed to work, but after a while I noticed it had disappeared from `.git/config` again, presumably by some kind of automatic generation by IntelliJ...

Answer (score 1):

Today installed PhpStorm 2022.2, set up my project and tried to commit - and got error "author is not *userName* and matches no existing author".
I searched the fix for problem, found this question and tried option with file in .git folder, but that did not work.
Then I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318375/fatal-no-existing-author-found-with-xxx) and have done next commands in common terminal:

```
git config user.name "User Name"
git config user.email "userName@test.com"
```

After that I returned to PHPStorm, invoked commit window and tried to commit without any author clarifying and got next dialog window:
[image]

I entered the same name and email I previously had entered into git via "git config" and all worked. I could not test this scenario well but maybe this experience can give some help with fixing the issue