# fatal: --author 'First Last example@example.com' is not 'Name <email>' and matches no existing author

Tags: git, git-commit, author, git-amend

I ran into this error when trying to amend a commit to change the author.

```
git commit --amend --author="First Last example@example.com"
```

```
fatal: --author 'First Last example@example.com' is not 'Name <email>' and matches no existing author
```

It is similar to an issue described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318375/fatal-no-existing-author-found-with-xxx), but the error message is different, making that solution difficult to find.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, the problem was not putting angle brackets around my email address. Changing the command to

```
git commit --amend --author="First Last <example@example.com>"
```

resolved the error.